# Bash curl Delete with cookies

Tags: bash, curl, http-delete

This works:

```
curl "https://website.com/stuff" -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt
```

I need to do the same request, but change the method to delete. From what I can tell it should be as simple as

```
curl -X DELETE "https://website.com/stuff" -c cookie.txt -b cookie.txt
```

I end up with a "Bad Credentials" response. The credentials are in the cookies, and the previous GET request wouldn't work unless the credentials are valid. Therefore I'm the syntax is wrong and it's ignoring the cookies.

I've attempted many permutations of the above. No idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you run it with `-v` and see if you get all the headers you expect, and if no.. elaborate on what's missing?